# Unable to clone Git repository using Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, clone, azure

I'm trying to clone WinJS to my Azure Web Site using Visual Studio Online "Monaco". When I type `git clone https://github.com/winjs/winjs.git` in the online console I get the error `Can only clone a git repository to the root of the workspace.`.

The "prefix" in the console is `/ $` so I guess I'm in the root already.

How do I clone a git repo using Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must delete every single folder under your `wwwroot` folder. Including `env` and `.git`

After this you should click on git icon and give the link of your repository. When the username and the password inserted correctly, the clone process starts immediately.

[image: Azure Online VS clone git repository]

Answer (score 0):

That would create a winjs folder, so it wouldn't be in the root. You can try with a period:

```
git clone https://github.com/winjs/winjs.git .
```

But the simpler way is to click on the git icon and use the clone UI there instead of doing it from the command line.